# Nativescript - cocoapod / Google Conversion Tracking

Tags: javascript, ios, cocoapods, tracking, nativescript

My question is how to actually implement and use cocoapod modules in iOS, I want to use the Google Conversion Tracking pod in my nativescript application but i cant get it to work. I can install the pod, but when i try to use it, i am not possible to.

Is there any good guides for how to implement cocoapod modules with nativescript ?

this is the code i try to run in my ***app.module.ts***

```
class MyDelegate extends UIResponder implements UIApplicationDelegate {
public static ObjCProtocols = [UIApplicationDelegate];

applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions(application: UIApplication, launchOptions: NSDictionary): boolean {
    console.log("applicationWillFinishLaunchingWithOptions");

// Google iOS in-app conversion tracking snippet
// Add this code to the event you'd like to track in your [ACTAutomatedUsageTracker enableAutomatedUsageReportingWithConversionID:@"12345678"];
  //ACTConversionReporter.reportWithConversionIDLabelValueIsRepeatable("12345678", "AASsoighsingaxx", "0.00", true);
[ACTConversionReporter reportWithConversionID:@"12345678" label:@"AASsoighsingaxx" value:@"0.00" isRepeatable:YES];  

    return true;
}

applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication): void {
    console.log("applicationDidBecomeActive: " + application)
  }
}
application.ios.delegate = MyDelegate;
```

am i support to declare any imports ? and if so, how?
I install the pod with using the method explained on https://docs.nativescript.org/plugins/cocoapods.

Answer (score 0):

To use a cocoapod, you must create a NativeScript plugin which imports the cocoapod via a Podfile. For an example, check out [the Podfile in my nativescript-midi plugin](https://github.com/BinaryNate/nativescript-midi/blob/master/platforms/ios/Podfile).

The Objective-C classes from your Cocoapod will be available as global objects once you install your plugin with the following command:

```
tns plugin install ../path/to/plugin
```

Since the Objective-C classes are exposed globally, you utilize them without importing them. Check out [the IosMidiDeviceManager class in my plugin](https://github.com/BinaryNate/nativescript-midi/blob/master/src/ios/IosMidiDeviceManager.js#L19) for an example of this. At the top of the file, I include a comment to instruct JSHint not to complain about using PGMidi without declaring it, but otherwise I just instantiate and use it directly.